# How does the NASB render καρδίαν as quick in Acts 7:54?

Tags: greek, acts, translation-philosophy, kjv, nasb

Ὡς δὲ ἐπληροῦτο αὐτῷ τεσσαρακονταετὴς χρόνος, ἀνέβη ἐπὶ τὴν ***καρδίαν*** αὐτοῦ ἐπισκέψασθαι τοὺς ἀδελφοὺς αὐτοῦ τοὺς υἱοὺς Ἰσραήλ.

Most translations render καρδίαν as heart but the NASB chose to translate it as quick

Acts 7:54 NASB

54 Now when they heard this, they were cut to the ***quick***, and they began gnashing their teeth at him.

Acts 7:54 KJV

54 When they heard these things, they were cut to the ***heart***, and they gnashed on him with their teeth.

Acts 7:54 YLT

54 And hearing these things, they were cut to the ***hearts***, and did gnash the teeth at him;

How can we understand this translation?

Comment: See Stack Exchange - English Language and Usage - [Etymology of Quick as in  'Cut to the Quick'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/etymology-of-quick-of-a-fingernail-as-in-cut-to-the-quick). This is an English idiom and the linked article also refers to 'the quick and the dead'. +1.

Comment: This is primarily an English language question, and belongs on a [different](http://english.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @Lucian,so you decided to downvote

Comment: Yes. I find downvotes devoid of explanations unconstructive, hence the previous comment.

Comment: @lucian,i find it strange that most of my questions have been downvoted by you .well i will stop asking questions if that will make you happy

Comment: @collenndhlovu: I *don't* want you to *stop* asking questions; I want you to *start* asking serious questions (as opposed to those that one can answer for oneself by performing a basic google search, or by simply consulting a dictionary). I admire your zeal and interest in scripture, and, in your picture, you seem to be a young man; so maybe I might seem a bit harsh, even though this is not my intent.

Comment: Your questions are always informative and it is quite clear that the huge majority of users on this site have appreciated them, witness your high reputation score in such a short period of time. You have no cause to be concerned about the petty criticisms of a single individual.

Comment: @NigelJThank you ,English is not my first language so some things may not be as simply as he imagines.Even when i have asked good questions he is the only one who l downvotes them

Comment: It was a little confusing for me when you cited Acts 7:23, but asked about the English of Acts 7:54. Better to take away the Greek (wrong verse).

Comment: This English translations deals with the English language, that doesn't mean all translation issues should be transferred to the English Stack. This is a valid and interesting topic, and I'm sure many will benefit from it. I am surprised that I never saw this NASB translation of the verse before. It is very strange!

Answer (score 2):

The large variation in translations of Acts 7:54 does not concern the word καρδίαν but the word διεπρίοντο.  Let me be more specific.  Here is my very literal translation of the Greek of the first half of the verse:

> Now hearing these things, they were sawn assunder into the heart ...

The word διαπρίω (diaprió) only occurs in Acts 5:33 and 7:54.  It is literally, "cut in two" but idiomatically means to "be infuriated" (BDAG).  The addition of the phrase ταῖς καρδίαις (in the hearts) intensifies this meaning.  Thus, I would translate this verse as:

> Now hearing these things, they were infuriated to the core ...

This is precisely the meaning conveyed in most versions:

- NIV: When the members of the Sanhedrin heard this, they were furious ...
- NLT: The Jewish leaders were infuriated ...
- ESV: Now when they heard these things they were enraged ...
- BSB: On hearing this, the members of the Sanhedrin were enraged ...
- CSB: When they heard these things, they were enraged ...
- CEV: they were angry and furious ...
- GNT: they became furious ...
- HCSB: When they heard these things, they were enraged in their hearts ...
- ISV: While they were listening to these things, they became more and more furious ...

Such a meaning, "became furious/enraged" is confirmed by that which follows, "they gnashed their teeth at him" also indicating uncontrolled rage.

We may also see that Acts 5:33, the same word διαπρίω (diaprió) is used with the same meaning of become enraged or very angry with the result of death threats.

A form of this idiom survives into modern English when we say, "beside myself with rage", meaning, I have to be divided into two people to express how angry I am.